# Take the audio of the youtube video element

Tags: audio, video, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

**Intro:**

I want to play a youtube video clip and be able to define its states during the session (to sync between users). I want that the youtube video will be played on the current chosen devices (webrtc app). E.g - I can choose specific audio output for the app from 3 that I have.

**The problem that I have:**

I am trying to get the youtube video audio in order to sink the audio to the relevant audio output device that I have. Currently, When I am playing the youtube video, the audio is being played through the current **default** audio output device and not by the chosen one on my app (I have the selected device id saved).

**What I actually want to achieve:**

I want to play the youtube player and hear the video audio track with the chosen audio output device (aka chosen speaker) and not by the default one.

**What I am using**
Currently using React-Player with my addons.
I am using React and Node

**Again:**

The problem here is that the video will be played on the default audio output of each client (cannot attach it to a specific one)

**setSindId is not reachable**

Ideas:

- Take the video element and get the audio track - not possible with iframe
- using youtube API for it - never seen an option
- Have some ideas regarding saving it as mp3 and serve the audio + doing sync footwork, I prefer not to.

Please let me know if you have an idea.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic) and provide a [mre].

Comment: Use the [edit option](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65171740/edit) to update your question. **(1)** Not clear what **exactly** you're asking (try to solve one task at a time _eg:_ extracting audio bytes data, or HTTP requests for sending, or monitoring changes... which one to solve first? Because there is no 1 answer for solving 3 very different problems) ... **(2)** Explain meaning of _"...Monitor when it changes"_. Normally an uploaded (stored) video doesn't change its audio at later time, maybe you're asking how to check if YT video link is now changed to deleted / private?